# How to store a value from Tkinter.Button on a var

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm novice with python.
So i'm trying to make a GUI, when i click the button will open a directory selector(see on code 1),and i need storage the path from selection that i expected receive on *"command"* in a var, so i can use the directory path for another things.

**Code 1**
*css.py*

```
...
def selectFolder():
    path = customtkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()
    return path
```

**Code 2**
*css.py*

```
def button(root,txt,event = any):
    button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master = root,text=txt,command = event)
    return button;
...
```

**Main code**
*main.py*

```
root = css.root()
frame = css.frame(root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill='both',expand=True)
label = css.label(frame,'Tecverde - Engenharia S.A','Roboto',10)
label.pack(pady=12, padx=10)
path = css.button(frame,"Selecione a pasta",css.selectFolder)
path.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The simplest solution would be to make `path` a global variable.  (It is pointless to `return` anything from a Button's `command=` function; you're not the one calling the function, and Tkinter isn't going to do anything with the return value.)

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using custontkinter, so all your widgets are 'CTk...'
2. Your button widgets can contain 'commands', my suggestion is, inside the function passed to the 'ask' command you can use tkinter's filedialog module, and use the output as needed.

This is an example of using Stringvar, a tkinter dynamic variable, whenever you use the command set('') in it you will modify its value for the entire code, and to get the value you can use .get () anywhere in the code.
Note that the debug label text changes after you dynamically select a directory.

```py
from tkinter import filedialog

import customtkinter as css

root = css.CTk()
frame = css.CTkFrame(root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill='both', expand=True)
label = css.CTkLabel(frame, text='Tecverde - Engenharia S.A', font=('Roboto', 10))
label.pack(pady=12, padx=10)


def ask():
    dir = filedialog.askdirectory()
    path_var.set(dir)


path_var = css.StringVar(value='Empty Path')

path_button = css.CTkButton(frame, text="Selecione a pasta",
                            command=ask)
path_button.pack()

debug_label = css.CTkLabel(root, textvariable=path_var)
debug_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In the second example, now using classes, self.path_var can be used anywhere in your code, even with a Stringvar as in the previous example, but now it has more options.

```py
from tkinter import filedialog

import customtkinter as css


class App(css.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        frame = css.CTkFrame(self)
        frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill='both', expand=True)

        label = css.CTkLabel(frame, text='Tecverde - Engenharia S.A', font=('Roboto', 10))
        label.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

        self.path_var = 'Empty path'

        path_button = css.CTkButton(frame, text="Selecione a pasta",
                                    command=self.ask)
        path_button.pack()

        self.debug_label = css.CTkLabel(self, text=self.path_var)
        self.debug_label.pack()

    def ask(self):
        dir = filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.path_var = dir
        self.debug_label.configure(text=dir)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: In this way, my var is filled before i call the ask directory https://prnt.sc/Q8M6wU0zl6Zw

Comment: Try use command=selectFolder without brackets, if you use brackets, func is called before use, or upload your code, is working for me.

Comment: i wanna receive the path value to continue my code but outside the function, after the path.pack()

Comment: For this you can use classes, or a global variable for example, I will edit my code with examples